# iOS8 - Get country names from locale

Tags: ios8, nslocale

I'm using this code to get the list of countries:

```
for (NSString *code in [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes])
{
    NSString *identifier = [NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents:@{NSLocaleCountryCode: code}];
    NSString *countryName = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:identifier];
    NSLog(countryName);
}
```

This works fine in iOS 7.x but fails in iOS8 (beta 2) - with `countryName` always being **nil**.

Anyone found an alternative yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also faced with such issue on iOS 8. Try to use `systemLocale` instead of `currentLocale`.

Comment: still nil on iOS 8, 9 and 10.

Comment: I just tried on iOS 10, it is not nil: https://monosnap.com/file/PbLByAmSdFmzkVRfyPckTaF2qSrjSh.png

Comment: By the way, on iOS 10 even variant with currentLocale outputs full country names (Ascension Island, Andorra, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    let currentLocale : NSLocale = NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier :  NSLocale.current.identifier)
    let countryName : String? = currentLocale.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode, value: countryCode)
    print(countryName ?? "Invalid country code")
```

Note: If you manually entered localIdentifier means IOS 8 not listed all country name (Eg: "en_US")